# How to Automate a curve fitting process in python?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm having a table containing x and y values for different time points. My dataset will be like this.

| x_15min | y_15min | x_30min | y_30min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0015 | 0.005899 | 0.0154 | 0.235 |
| 0.001734 | 0.0101 | 0.0145 | 0.254 |

I want to fit a linear equation, calculate r2 value and save the plot for x_15min and y_15min. Then I want to repeat the same work for x_30min and y_30min, and it will goes. I want to know how to automate the python to do the same work.

My code is:

```
a = 'x_15min'

b = 'y_15min' 

#Fitting with a line

p = np.polyfit(a,b,1)

print(p)

plt.plot(a,b, 'o', label = 'exp values')

plt.plot(a, np.polyval(p,a), label = 'model fit')
plt.savefig('15min_curvefit.jpg')

print ('R^2 Value for 15 min sample', r2_score(b, np.polyval(p,b)))
```

Could someone guide me how to repeat the same process for different timepoints [from the same dataset]

Comment: Hi, this looks more like "I need a tutorial"-question rather than a specific programming question. Nevertheless, in what form do you have your data. CSV, Excel, other? Is it already imported. As a general tip. try to provide code that is stand-alone and works, i.e. a minimal working example.

Comment: The data was a csv file. I uploaded through Pandas.

Comment: I see why people use pandas, but for me it seems an unnecessary overload. I'd load it with `numpy` and just loop over the columns like `n = len( data[0] // 2 )` and then a loop and checking `data[ ::, 2 * i ]` and `data[ ::, 2 * i + 1 ]`